# Method between $this->_data and $this->data

Tags: php

For my knowledge I will know what are the major difference between

```
$this->_data
```

and

```
$this->data
```

if they could show by example the approach.
Thank you.

.

Comment: No Difference other than you have one property called `data` and another called `_data`

Comment: There's no difference. A property starting with `_` is *sometimes* used to indicate that it's some sort of internal/temporary value you're not supposed to touch, but that's not a formal PHP thing at all.

Comment: The difference here is '_'

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual difference. It's just a common practice to prefix private properties with an underline for clarity inside the classes.

Comment: Common practice for some, uncommon (or even undesired) for others ;)

Comment: Well yes, but still it is generally quite common in many programming languages. :)